# C socket not running on Mac OS X

Tags: c, macos, sockets

The following code runs and communicates with the client without a problem on Ubuntu. However, I need to run on Mac OS X. I can compile it with no errors however when I am trying to run it the following message appears: *"Abort trap: 6"*. I tried to google it but cannot find any useful information about it. Even if I put a printf in the beginning of the main function it does not run. Thank you for any suggestion.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/un.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#define UNIX_PATH_MAX 108

int connection_handler(int connection_fd)
{
    int nbytes;
    char buffer[256];

    nbytes = read(connection_fd, buffer, 256);
    buffer[nbytes] = 0;

    printf("MESSAGE FROM CLIENT: %s\n", buffer);
    nbytes = snprintf(buffer, 256, "hello from the server");
    write(connection_fd, buffer, nbytes);

    close(connection_fd);
     return 0;
}

int main(void)
{
    struct sockaddr_un address;
    int socket_fd, connection_fd;
    socklen_t address_length;
    pid_t child;

    socket_fd = socket(PF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    if(socket_fd < 0)
    {
        printf("socket() failed\n");
        return 1;
    } 

    unlink("./demo_socket");

    /* start with a clean address structure */
    memset(&address, 0, sizeof(struct sockaddr_un));
    address.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
    snprintf(address.sun_path, UNIX_PATH_MAX, "./demo_socket");

    if(bind(socket_fd, (struct sockaddr *) &address, sizeof(struct sockaddr_un)) != 0)
    {
        printf("bind() failed\n");
        return 1;
    }

    if(listen(socket_fd, 5) != 0)
    {
        printf("listen() failed\n");
        return 1;
    }

    while((connection_fd = accept(socket_fd, (struct sockaddr *) &address,&address_length)) > -1)
    {
        child = fork();
        if(child == 0)
        {
            /* now inside newly created connection handling process */
            return connection_handler(connection_fd);
        }
        /* still inside server process */
        close(connection_fd);
    }

    close(socket_fd);
    unlink("./demo_socket");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You might want to run it in a debugger.

Comment: One thing that caught my eye in `connection_handler` is that you don't check for error from the `read` call. What do think will happen when it fails and return `-1`?

Answer (score 4):

You have `UNIX_PATH_MAX` hard-coded to 108, but `sun_path` in `sockaddr_un` is only 104 bytes long:

```
struct  sockaddr_un {
    unsigned char   sun_len;    /* sockaddr len including null */
    sa_family_t sun_family; /* [XSI] AF_UNIX */
    char        sun_path[104];  /* [XSI] path name (gag) */
};
```

So you're trying to write outside the buffer with the following:

```
snprintf(address.sun_path, UNIX_PATH_MAX, "./demo_socket");
```

You can fix this with:

```
snprintf(address.sun_path, sizeof(address.sun_path), "./demo_socket");
```

This would have been an easy fix if you had used a debugger (such as gdb).

Answer (score 0):

A possible cause is that you don't initialize `address_length` before calling `accept`. `accept` *needs* it to be properly initialized before the call.